# Selenium Driver for IE is not executing implicit wait statements

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

It is observed that, selenium IE driver is not doing implicit wait while loading a new page, if an element is rendered after 2-3 seconds it fails immediately . I have given implicit wait as 5 minutes

Comment: if your observations are correct, then this should be created as a Selenium issue.  File a ticket: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to set the implicit wait time and what version of selenium you are using, it works for me.